# Identifying AGPM changes not yet in production

Tags: group-policy

How do I find AGPM checked in changes that haven't yet been pushed to production?

It seems like this should be easy, but I haven't found documentation anywhere. 
I was originally thinking that the 'Pending' tab would indicate this status, however it appears that this is only populated [if someone without right tried and failed to deploy a change.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.01.agpm.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to identify these policies. Anything that is in AGPM but not yet merged to production is kept in a policy marked as `[AGPM] <Original Policy Name>` under the group policy objects for the domain.